# Refresh and Clear button aren't working on asp.net application

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server, knockout.js

My 'Clear' and 'Refresh' buttons do not clear out my Branch and Terminal inputs on my webpage. I think it has something to do with my KnockoutJS since I bind the data to a table in the DB. Perhaps the KnockoutJS thing isn't functioning properly. The page is supposed to display the fetched data from the DB everytime 'Refresh' button is clicked too. But it seems like the code doesn't even fetch anything from the DB. 
I'm new to learning the framework of asp.net so can anyone pls help me w my issue? T

I tried to look at other API functions and only tweaked a little parameters to fetch from the DB since there are different tables I need to fetch from. I also modified the Stored Procedure of the respective page for the API function to grab the data from SQL Server but still the page appears blank and the buttons aren't working.

buttons html

```
 <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 m-b-15">
                            <button id="btnRefreshForecastDetails" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom w-md waves-effect waves-light" data-bind="click: refresh"><i class="mdi mdi-refresh"></i> <span>Refresh</span></button>
                            <button id="btnClearAll" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom w-md waves-effect waves-light" onclick="ClearAll();"><i class="mdi mdi-close"></i> <span>Clear All</span></button>

                        </div>
```

.JS function

```
    var ObservableModelMain = function () {
var self = this;
self.gifts = ko.observableArray();

self.refresh = function () {
    StartLoadingPage();
    url = sessionStorage.getItem('WebApiURL') + "IT_GetDetails?ID=" + sessionStorage.getItem('ID');
    var table = $('#main-table');//table from DB
    var PageSize = sessionStorage.getItem('PageSize');
    var valueToPush = {};
    var FinalData = [];
    valueToPush.PageNumber = table.getPageNum();
    valueToPush.PageSize = PageSize;
    valueToPush.SortExpression = table.getSortExpression();
    valueToPush.SortOrder = table.getSortOrder();
    valueToPush.SearchBranchNo = _strSearchBranchNo;
    valueToPush.SearchTerminalNo = _strSearchTerminalNo;
    valueToPush.SearchDate = _strSearchDate;
    FinalData.push(valueToPush);
    valueToPush = {};
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(FinalData)

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: myJSON,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            DeviceStatus = data["errorCode"];
            Param = data["param"];
            if (DeviceStatus == 'SUCCESS') {
                var obj = JSON.parse(Param);

                if (obj[0].length == 0 && obj[1][0].TotalOutput != 0) {
                    document.getElementById('btnRefreshForecastDetails').click();
                }
                else {
                    self.gifts(obj[0]);
                }

                table.updateTable(parseInt(PageSize), obj[1][0].TotalOutput);
                //GetBranchList();
            }
            else {
                swal("Error", "Fail to retrieve forecast details, " + Param, "error");
            }

            CloseLoadingPage();
        }
    });
}
    };
```

API function

```
    public async Task<TCR_RESPONSEMESSAGE> IT_GetForecastDetails(ITForecast[] Alldata)
    {
        StringBuilder sbReturnMessage = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbTraceMessage = new StringBuilder();
        API_COMPLETEMESSAGE tcm = null;
        WebAPITraceLog wtl = null;
        string reqStr = string.Empty;
        string repStr = string.Empty;
        string MessageSeqNo = string.Empty;
        const string functionNameStr = nameof(IT_GetForecastDetails);
        API_FUNCTION APIFunctionCode = API_FUNCTION.IT_GetForecastDetails;

        StringBuilder sbSQLStmt = new StringBuilder();
        bool asyncResult = false;
        DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
        bool blnResult = false;
        string strTable = "tblForecastDetails";
        List<SqlParameter> SqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection SQLDBConn = new SqlConnection(sqlTCRSecureBODBConnStr))
            {
                await SQLDBConn.OpenAsync();

                SqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PageNumber", Alldata[0].PageNumber));
                SqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PageSize", Alldata[0].PageSize));
                SqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SortExpression", Alldata[0].SortExpression));
                SqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SortOrder", Alldata[0].SortOrder));

                SqlParameter OutputParam = new SqlParameter("@TotalRecords", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                OutputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                SqlParameters.Add(OutputParam);

                blnResult = ReadDataSetByStoredProcedure("GetForecastDetailsWithPage", SqlParameters, strTable, DEFAULT_LOG_NAME, SQLDBConn, ref dsData);

                if (blnResult == false)
                {
                    tcm = FAIL_READ_MESSAGE;
                    tcm.Param = "Fail to read GetForecastDetailsWithPage.";
                    goto ExitHandler;
                }

                DataTable tbl = new DataTable("tblPagerInfo");

                tbl.Columns.Add("TotalOutput", typeof(long));

                tbl.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt64(SqlParameters[4].Value));

                dsData.Tables.Add(tbl);
            }

            if (dsData != null)
            {
                tcm = SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
                tcm.Param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsData.Tables);
                goto ExitHandler;
            }
            else
            {
                tcm = FAIL_READ_MESSAGE;
                tcm.Param = "Fail to read GetForecastDetailsWithPage.";
                goto ExitHandler;
            }

            ExitHandler:
            tcm.Function = APIFunctionCode;
            return await ProcessAPICompleteMessage(tcm, functionNameStr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessages = string.Empty;
            errorMessages += "Description : " + ex.Message;
            LogError(DEFAULT_LOG_PATH, DEFAULT_LOG_NAME, errorMessages, GetLineNumber(ex).ToString(), functionNameStr);
            tcm = EXCEPTION_MESSAGE;
            tcm.Function = APIFunctionCode;
            tcm.Param = errorMessages;
            return await ProcessAPICompleteMessage(tcm, functionNameStr);
        }
    }
```

I expect for the "Refresh" and "Clear" buttons to work, and for the DB data from the declared table to be fetched to be displayed on the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, for starters I don't see your knockout anywhere being bound to your viewmodel, preferably below your viewmodel definition.

```
ko.applyBindings(new ObservableModelMain());
```

and secondly your clear button has a plain old javascript `onclick` event attribute, not a data-bind to a -also not available- `self.clear = function() {...}` in your knockout viewmodel